# Animation loop keeps playing when editing in 2.8

Tags: edit-mode, keyframes

I'm messing around with blender 2.8 & everytime i am in either edit or object mode, in the initial tab. The animation loop keeps starting in the bottom window, I thought I had solved it by changing that window to a normal text editor instead of the keyframes interface but its still doing it? can this be stopped?

Comment: did you try pressing Space or Shift+Space to stop playback?

Comment: No, thats half the problem.. When using the knife tool i'm using space bar to confirm any cuts or other actions. As mentioned in a youtube tutorial.

Comment: That tutorial probably has custom shortcuts as spacebar by default is used for playback.

Comment: its not custom hot keys as it does confirm actions also as standard setup?

Comment: Try loading factory settings (file>defaults>load factory settings) in a new file and try the knife tool on the default cube and confirm with space. If it works then you might have a changed something in your custom configuration that causes the looping playback.